# Where are all the Khajiits?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I wanted a Khajiit steward for my house because that would be awesome but I realized that I have only seen one Khajiit camp in Skyrim. I was wondering if there are camps throughout Skyrim or if there are caravan routes that would help me find some?

Answer (score 12):

Khajiit are used to more temperate climes by far; they don't like the cold, and their native province, Elsweyr, is far to the south of Skyrim.

The distance from home combined with an unideal climate (and Nord racism) means very few Khajiit are found this far north. As such, there are very few Khajiit in Skyrim; they have no settlements of their own, and the only reasonable concentration of Khajiit at all are in the wandering "gypsy" caravans.

The UESP counts only [25 Khajiit](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Khajiit) in all of Skyrim (Compare this to the 500 or so Nords!), and they are the only race without marriage candidates in the base game.

The aforementioned ["Caravan" Khajiit](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Khajiit_Traders) have the following routes:

```
 - Ri'saad's Group travels between Whiterun and Markarth
 - Ahkari's Group travels between Riften and Dawnstar
 - Ma'dran's Group travels between Windhelm and Solitude
```

Each caravan will stay camped outside the appropriate city for 2 days before traveling along the road to the other.

Comment: Wow that helps out a lot. I don't think I've accepted a Khajiik related quest so it'll be nice to learn about they're history. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

There are three [Khajiit trader](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Khajiit_Traders) groups and they follow fixed routes.

- Ri'saad's Group travels between Whiterun and Markarth
- Ahkari's Group travels between Riften and Dawnstar
- Ma'dran's Group travels between Windhelm and Solitude

These traders will often camp out at one of the cities on their route for a few days before moving on.

Answer (score 4):

No one seems to have addressed his primary question which is:

> I wanted a Khajiit stewart for my house because that would be awesome

Unfortunately, in the base game, none of the possible Stewards are Khajiit:

https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Skyrim:_Possible_Stewards

There is at least one mod which offers this as an option:

[Dominions Hearthfire Stewards](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/7299/)

Also, on the XBox One there is another one:

[Beast Mode](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4021385)

Answer (score -1):

You can get a Khajiit follower by returning the moon amulet to Kharjo, then taking him to your house and asking him to be your steward.

Comment: Unfortunately Kharjo is not a possible steward in the base game:  https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Skyrim:_Possible_Stewards

Comment: Followers are not always stewards. Serana can be a follower but not a steward.